# How to cancel event from onstart Javascript call

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How can I cancel event from `onstart` javascript function?

I've tried this, but the event is not canceled. Button code:

```
<p:commandButton id="cmbtInsertar" value=Insertar"
    onstart="return verificarNulidad();"
</p:commandButton>
```

and the function code:

```
function verificarNulidad() 
{   
    puedeInsertar = true;

    var frm = document.getElementById("formInicio");

    for (var i=0; i<frm.elements.length;i++)
    {   
        if((frm.elements[i].id.indexOf("XX") != -1 || frm.elements[i].id.indexOf("XX") != '-1') && (frm.elements[i].id.indexOf("focus") == -1 || frm.elements[i].id.indexOf("focus") == '-1')) 
        {
            var nombreCampo = (frm.elements[i].id.substring(frm.elements[i].id.indexOf("_")+1)).replace('_input','');

            if(frm.elements[i].value == null || frm.elements[i].value.trim == '' )
            {
                alert('El Campo '+nombreCampo+' no puede estar en blanco');
                puedeInsertar = false;
                frm.elements[i].focus;
                break;  
            }
            else if(frm.elements[i].value == '0' || frm.elements[i].value == 0 || frm.elements[i].value == '-1' || frm.elements[i].value == -1)
            {
                alert('El Campo '+nombreCampo+' no puede ser cero');
                puedeInsertar = false;
                frm.elements[i].focus;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    return puedeInsertar;   
}
```

Comment: Which PF version? There was a bug like that in an ancient PF 2.x version. But it should already be fixed for long in 3.x/4.x. What happens when you try `onstart="return false"`? In any case, the `onclick` is a much better tool for the particular job. Or, functionally, just relying on JSF builtin validation facilities instead of homebrewing some JS.

Comment: The PF version is 4, when try onstart="return false" in fact the event is canceled, but when the return value is true, does a redirect which is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend calling the JavaScript function in your button, and decide in that function, when to call the bean method. PrimeFaces has `p:remoteCommand` component for that task

```xml
<p:remoteCommand name="myCommand" actionListener="#{myBean.myCommand}" update=":myForm:mySth"/>

<p:commandButton value="Insertar" onclick="if (verificarNulidad()) myCommand()"/>
```

Comment: myCommand not the method runs, which would be a possible cause?